# what is iOS pack id

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

I'm relatively new to mobile development, so I'm trying to make and app that uses de facebook api to share some content of the app directly on the user wall. but registering the app  on facebook I'm asked for a "iOS pack Id" and there is no documentation about it on the page.

So I wonder if anybody knows what is this id and where I can find it?

Answer (score 1):

This is your iOS Bundle package ID. Here is a tutorial (some is in spanish) that explains it. Look at section 3. http://wiki.gxtechnical.com/commwiki/servlet/hwiki?HowTo%3A+Register+a+Facebook+App+for+Smart+Device+interaction,

You can get your Bundle ID by selecting your project and selecting your application target, Select the **Summary** tab, this will be the first value **Bundle Identifier**